# Styling validation messages in html form

Tags: html, css, forms

I am attempting to style my form HTML generated by my ASP.NET MVC 3 application. With the default styles the labels stack on top of the input controls like so:

[image]

I have altered the css so that the label sits to the left of the input control like this:

[image]

However I have a problem when the input control is a text area and the validation message is shown:

[image]

As you can see the validation message is lined up with the bottom of the text area. **I would like it to line up with the top of the text area.**

This is a good approximation of the HTML generated by the MVC scaffolding (The structure is identical but I have omitted some of the HTML attributes):

```
<Fieldset>
    <Legend>Form Title</Legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <label>Town / City</Label>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        <textArea></textArea>
        <span class="field-validation-error">
            <span>The town / city field is required</span>
        </span>
    </div>

</Fieldset>
```

and this is my current css:

```
.editor-label {
    margin: .8em 0 0 .5em;
    clear: left;
    float:left;
    width: 160px;
}

.editor-field {
    margin: .5em 0 0 0;
    float: left;
}
```

I have tried adding a style that targets the `<span>` with a class of `field-validation-error` and the `<textarea>` and settin their `display` property to `inline-block` but this doesn't change the way the validation error is displayed.

```
.field-validation-error {
    color: #FF0000;
    display: inline-block;
}

textarea {
    font: inherit;
    min-height: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Is there a way to target the span element and display in line with the top of the textarea?
Ideally, I don't want to have to alter the HTML (as this is auto-generated by ASP.NET MVC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float the text area to the left-

```
textarea {
  float:left;
}
```

new Demo http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/wCVK2/1/

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way of doing it without re-ordering the HTML?

Comment: Superb. I can't believe it was that simple (and that I couldn't figure it out myself...very embarrassing) Thank you for your help.